# Как получить уникальный Android device ID?

Tags: java, android

Мне кажется это один из стандартных вопросов "Как присвоить юзеру уникальный ID" и я столкнулся с тем, что способы сделать это есть разные согласно этой [статье](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/27109/) на хабре, можно получать IMEI, Wi-Fi Mac адрес, Androif BlueTooth ID либо генерировать его таким образом

```
String deviceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

и прочее. И присваивать как уникальный номер юзеру. Но мне стало интересно, действительно гугл никак не реализовал стандартный алгоритм решения такой ситуации и если так, то какому все таки варианту опытные разработчики отдают приоритет, чтоб избежать возможных ошибок?

Comment: Всё зависит от реализации, для чего будет использоваться. Вопрос конкретный, я дал по нему ответ, но просто хочу сказать, что в любом случае есть возможность изменения этого значения, и не стоит создать для app ещё одну зависимость, какой бы уникальной она не была, если в этом нет необходимости.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final String ANDROID_ID = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Какой в данном случае возвращается ID? я имею ввиду насколько он будет уникальным? Это лучше чем `String deviceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()` ?

Comment: Это разные генерации(хотя зависимость есть), опять же повторюсь будет зависеть для чего будет применяться. ANDROID_ID генерирует user и id device (возможно что-то ещё) в hex_string 64бит, а randomUUID() будет генерировать просто случайно значение по алгоритму. Те в перовом случае вы получаете уникальный номер относительно device(зависящий от пользователя), а во втором применяете алгоритм UUID. Насчет уникальности есть пример на wiki, если генерировать 1 миллиард UUID, каждую секунду в течение следующих 100 лет, вероятность создания только одно дубликата будет примерно 50%.

Comment: Кроме того, несмотря на уникальность Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID, этот идентификатор может меняться при factory reset`е или даже вручную, если девайс рутованный.

Comment: Да верно, поэтому я и написал комментарий в самом начале вопроса

Comment: ANDROID_ID будет постоянно один и тот же для устройства, а UUID каждый раз разный. Мне нужно присвоить юзеру уникальный ID для того, чтоб я мог занести его в DB чтоб они не повторялись в DB, значит я так понимаю, что лучше использовать UUID так как юзер может создать несколько аккаунтов на одном устройстве и если использовать ANDROID_ID то для всех аккаунтов в таком случае будет присваиваться один и тот же ID?

Comment: А чем тогда это будет отличаться от просто primaty_key в SQLite или БД не SQL? В теории можно, но что-то мне подсказывает, что можно этого избежать...